# vscode - java test runner : exclude directory from tests

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, junit

### Exclude folder from from Java Test Runner's - Test Explorer?

I'm writing integration tests in java using vscode.  I am really enjoying the java test runner plugin.  The only downside right now is that the test explorer is including .java files in my `src\test\java\com\testapp\Shared` folder that have 0 tests in them.  Is there a way to exclude this folder from the test explorer? Seeing them in the explorer doesn't affect anything but OCD is kicking my butt.

[image]

[Java Test runner for vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-test)

**Things I've tried**

in my settings.json, i tried to point to ONLY use the Services folder for testing.  Didn't filter the test explorer. :(

```
"java.test.config": [
        {
            "name": "unit",
            "workingDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/src/test/java/com/testapp/Services",
        },
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently(v0.25.0) the extension will show all the types in the test source paths. There is a tracking issue about this problem: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/768

*// Sorry my reputation is < 50, so I cannot directly comment on your question.*

Comment: Thanks for the link!  Hopefully a solution is found soon!